# My MacBook boots into recovery no matter what I select as a startup disk

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, recovery

My MacBook no longer boots into macOS after I tried installing rEFInd. Instead, it always boots into recovery mode no matter which disk I select.

**Before that (I know OS X El Capitan isn't officially supported on my MacBook), everything (except GPU Acceleration) was working great.**

I've tried booting into Safe Mode, running First Aid on Disk Utility and resetting the NVRAM and SMC without any luck and I can't reinstall macOS because I can't boot into the patched installer and the Installer from Recovery Mode isn't patched.

I think that my bootloader isn't working properly after I tried installing rEFInd

Here are the specs for my MacBook:

```
Model identifier : MacBook2,1
System : Patched OS X El Capitan
CPU : Intel Core 2 Duo (64Bit)
Name : Late-2006 MacBook
```

**I want to at least boot into the installation medium, so I can reinstall macOS**

The patcher I used for installing macOS/OS X El Capitan is [RMC's OSX PATCHER](https://github.com/rmc-team/osx-patcher)

Comment: Have you tried just letting it boot into recovery mode and following the directions there and then restarting?

Comment: jmh Yep, before even asking the question, but Infortunately, it didn't work . But thanks for trying to answer :) .

Comment: Normally, to boot in recovery mode, you hold the "Options", "Command", and "R" buttons until the boot chimes are triggered. Have you tried doing this to see what happens now.

Comment: jmh That just boots again into recovery (I've tried that also)

Comment: Have you tried resetting your mac?  erasing your disk?

Comment: jmh first : I don't tried erasing my disk but i will try, Second : I already tried reinstalling macOS in Recovery mode and, "ERROR : OS X El Capitan is already installed on this computer"

Comment: If you’ve solved your problem, please leave an answer below with your solution to help future visitors. Don’t bump your questions with trivial edits.

Comment: Was the solution to re-bless the drive with the original EFI file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the EFI Partition was faulty and that I still can boot into my Debian 10 Live Medium so the solution was to reinstall macOS or to fix the EFI partition

In my case, I simply need to reinstall macOS/OS X Snow Leopard and then repatch the El Capitan installer and install and then, I'm done (Yes, I can just repair the EFI partition but I've erased my disk without doing it in purpose).

In the case of others, just reinstalling (without erasing anything) will fix the issue.

I hope that everyone is doing well and that my answer helped.

Vitali64